# #Python3 pickle：TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: pickle

I want to save the nlp.doc(the document generated by spacy nlp model) by pickle dump commond, but I get type error.  Could you tell me how to fix this error or show me an alternative way to save nlp doc.

```
 import spacy
 import pickle
 nlp = spacy.load('en') 
 a="Hello Adam, how are you?"
 data=nlp(a)
 f = open('nlp1/test.pkl',mode='wb')
 pickle.dump(data,f)
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
---------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-27-3fd206f7756b> in <module>()
  5 data=nlp(a)
  6 f = open('nlp1/test.pkl',mode='wb')
 7 pickle.dump(data,f)

 doc.pyx in spacy.tokens.doc.pickle_doc()

 doc.pyx in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.to_bytes()

 ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py in 
 to_bytes(getters, exclude)
         if key not in exclude:
             serialized[key] = getter()
 return msgpack.dumps(serialized, use_bin_type=True, 
encoding='utf8')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack_numpy.py in 
packb(o, **kwargs)
194     """
return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
def unpack(stream, **kwargs):

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 
'encoding'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error points to line 486 in spacy's util.py. 
I deleted the encoding argument from .dumps() and it works.  Probably not a long-term solution, but a good temporary hack.

```
File "/user/anaconda/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 486, in to_bytes
    return msgpack.dumps(serialized, use_bin_type=True, encoding='utf8')
```